# Force liquibase to allow 24h timestamp

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I have a liquibase script initializing some data in an oracle database. It contains inserting of some timestamps, too.

```
INSERT INTO ACCTEST4.MAXVCOVERSION (VCOID, SPECIFICATIONVERSION, SPECIFICATIONTITLE, VERSIONGENERATORCLASS, REGISTRATIONTIME) VALUES ('xxxxxxxxxxxxx', '3.1.7', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', NULL, '05-Aug-2015 15:14:51')
```

Running that scripts on a machine with a language that's using 24H format for timestamps everything is fine, but changing to a machine using 12H timestamps I get an

```
ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
```

How can I solve this? Can I configure liquibase to force using 24H timestamps?

EDIT:
The statement is created using

```
      <loadData
            encoding="UTF-8"
            file="liquibase/v320/installSunriseDml/csv/MAXVCOVERSION.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="MAXVCOVERSION">
        <column name="VERSIONGENERATORCLASS" type="STRING" />
        <column name="SPECIFICATIONVERSION" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="VCOID" type="STRING"/>
        <column name="REGISTRATIONTIME" type="DATETIME"/>
        <column name="SPECIFICATIONTITLE" type="STRING"/>
      </loadData>
```

Comment: Use `TO_DATE()` to convert string to date... `TO_DATE('05-Aug-2015 15:14:51','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` So it behaves same in all sessions.

Comment: How is that statement generated by Liquibase? Is that a `loadUpdateData` command? Or a plain SQL script?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: updated question

Comment: And how is the date formatted in `MAXVCOVERSION.csv`?

Comment: 24H format, see example: "05-Aug-2015 15:14:51"

Comment: Did you read [the Liquibase manual](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html): "*Date/Time values included in the CSV file should be in ISO format in order to be parsed correctly by Liquibase*" and: "*if problems occur, then a ParseException is thrown and the input string is treated as a String for the INSERT command to be generated*"

Comment: That's hot. I'll check that. Thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85398/discussion-between-mibutec-and-a-horse-with-no-name).